# Visual Studio Extension: Access VS Options from arbitrary DLL

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte, vspackage

I'm currently developing my first VS extension, which needs to provide some options to the user. Following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx, it was rather easy to come up with my own options page. However, I have not yet found out how to read my options.

The solution structure of my extension is as follows:

```
MySolution
  MyProject (generates a DLL from C# code)
  MyProjectVSIX
```

Following the tutorial cited above, I have added a VS `Package` to my VSIX project and configured it as described. As a result, my options page with my options is shown under Tools/Options. Nice! Here's my `DialogPage` implementation:

```
public class OptionPageGrid : DialogPage
{
    private bool myOption = false;

    [Category(Options.CATEGORY_NAME)]
    [DisplayName("My option")]
    [Description("Description of my option.")]
    public bool MyOption
    {
        get { return myOption; }
        set { myOption = value; }
    }
}
```

And here's the head of my Package class:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]     [Guid(MyOptionsPage.PackageGuidString)]
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1650:ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly", Justification = "pkgdef, VS and vsixmanifest are valid VS terms")]
[ProvideOptionPage(typeof(OptionPageGrid), Options.CATEGORY_NAME, Options.PAGE_NAME, 0, 0, true)]
public sealed class MyOptionsPage : Package, IOptions
{
    ...
```

However, I now want to read those options, and I want to do it from MyProject (which does not have a dependency on MyProjectVSIX). And this is where I'm kind of lost. My first attempt was to let my `Package` implement an `IOptions` interface, and to let it register itself by calling a static method `Options.Register(IOptions)` from the `Package`'s constructor. This works (i.e., the breakpoint in `Register()` is hit), but when I try to read options, the static `IOptions` instance is still null. My assumption is that this is due to the fact that the code is executed from different processes (which is beyond my control).

After some more googling, I tried to get an instance of the `DTE` object (which would allow me to read my options if I correctly understood), but to no success. I've tried several variants, including the one described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834473.aspx and

```
DTE Dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
```

I always end up with a null reference.

Finally, since the tutorial suggested to access the options through the instance of `Package`, I tried to figure out how to obtain such an instance of my VS `Package` through some kind of registry (which I could than cast to `IOptions`), but again without luck.

Can anybody please point me to the right direction? Or is it even impossible to access VS options from a non-VSIX project?

**Update:** I have done some more research, and one piece of information was missing: My extension is a Unit Test Adapter. This seems to imply that the test discovery code as well as the test execution code are run from different processes, i.e., my assumption was right.

I have in the meantime managed to access the `DTE` object of the VS instance I'm running in (I will post that with my complete solution as soon as my problem is solved), but still have problems accessing the options. In fact, the following code (copied from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165641.aspx) works nicely:

```
Properties txtEdCS = DTEProvider.DTE.get_Properties("TextEditor", "CSharp");
Property prop = null;
string msg = null;
foreach (EnvDTE.Property temp in txtEdCS)
{
    prop = temp;
    msg += ("PROP NAME: " + prop.Name + "   VALUE: " + prop.Value) + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

However, if I change the above as follows:

```
Properties txtEdCS = DTEProvider.DTE.get_Properties(CATEGORY_NAME, PAGE_NAME);
```

Now the code crashes. Weirdly enough, I can see my property category and page in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp_Config\AutomationProperties\My Test Adapter\General`. Searching for my properties shows them under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\ApplicationPrivateSettings\MyProjectVSIX\OptionPageGrid` (mabye because I added

```
OptionPageGrid Page = (OptionPageGrid)GetDialogPage(typeof(OptionPageGrid));
Page.SaveSettingsToStorage();
```

to the `Package`'s `Initialize()` method (as Matze suggested), maybe because I haven't looked there before :-) ).

So how to read my properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS test adapter framework happens to have API for sharing settings accross processes. Since nothing is documented at all, it took a while to figure out how to use that API. For a working example see [this GitHub project](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter).

Update: The [vstest](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest) framework has recently been open-sourced by MS.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the options from within your package, you can just ask for an `OptionPageGrid` instance via the `GetDialogPage` method of the `VSPackage`. For instance:

```
var options = (OptionGridPage)this.package.GetDialogPage(typeof(OptionGridPage));
bool b = options.MyOption;
```

In case you want access the options from within another application (or an assembly which can be used without having the runtime environment of Visual Studio), you can try to read those settings right from the Windows registry, but the registry keys and values may not be present unless the options have been written by the `IDE` or your package. You can force persistence of the options by calling the `SaveSettingsToStorage` method from within your package, for instance on the first load:

```
options.SaveSettingsToStorage();
```

The settings will be stored under the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\DialogPage
```

whereby `12.0` indicates the version of Visual Studio. Under this key you´ll find a bunch of sub-keys whose names are the full names of the `DialogPage` component types. Each key contains the property values; in your case you should find a `REG_SZ` value named `MyOption` having either `True` or `False` as it´s data value.

Comment: We're hoping to one day deprecate registry persistence, so it's best to call through the various APIs if you at all can.

Comment: I thought about directly accessing the registry, but wanted to leave that as the very last option... The way to access my PropertyPage through its Package is also mentioned in the MS article I cited - the problem is how to access that Package from within my custom code. It turned out that I have indeed to deal with several processes - see my updated question...

Comment: Note that recent VS versions store settings in a private registry hive which is only accessible within VS process.

Comment: @DarkDaskin Interesting; I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is that this is due to the fact that the code is executed from different processes

Unless you're very explicitly writing stuff otherwise, all VS extensibility code runs in a single AppDomain under devenv.exe. If you're seeing it come up null, that means either your registration code didn't run, or didn't do what you thought it did.

You have a few options here:

1. Avoid the problem entirely: try refactoring your code such that the code in the non-VSIX project doesn't have to read stuff from the environment, but is passed options into some method call, and the VSIX project does that. This is often the best outcome, because it makes unit testing a lot easier. ("Global state" is always bad for testing.)
2. Have your non-VSIX project just have a static class for setting the options, and your VSIX project references the non-VSIX project and sets it when the settings get changed.
3. Register a service through the ProvideService attribute, and in your non-VSIX project still call `Package.GetGlobalService` for your own service type. This has the major caveat that GetGlobalService has a bunch of gotchas; I avoid that method in general due to the challenges involved with it.
4. Use MEF. If you are familiar with Import/Export attributes, you can have your VSIX project Export an interface defined in your non-VSIX project, and you import it. If you're familiar with the idea of dependency injection this is very nice, but the learning curve is really a learning cliff.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent recommendations, but I had forgotten one bit of information which I have now added - looks like my assumption was right. I'm from the Java world, so it took me a while to understand what's going on - sorry for not asking more precise... Despite that, I will most likely look into MEF out of interest,

Comment: Oh, the fact you're running in a different process changes this significantly. In general all of the methods I described for reading properties only work within the same process, so you'll need to have some way to shuttle the information over. I'm not familiar with test adapter extensibility to know if they have a design for that or not.

Note you might find come across code or recommendations to use DTE to read your options from the other process, which can be done. I wouldn't recommend that as you may risk deadlocks.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. Looks like I'm stuck with reading the options from the registry. However, since I only need to read them (and I am currently only planning support for VS2015 and beyond), that shouldn't be too bad. Still weird that the unit test adapter framework does not have API for things like that...

Comment: I'll send an e-mail tomorrow internally to see if can find somebody, but it'll take a few days given the teams are in some different time zones...

Comment: That would be plain awesome, thanks again! Note, please, that I would be most interested in some general documentation of the Test Adapter framework - I haven't found any official API documentation, only some blog entries...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an addition to my first answer. Of course, reading options from a spied registry key might be a dirty approach, because the implementation of the proprietary API could change in the future, which could break your extension. As Jason mentioned, you could try to "avoid the problem entirely"; for instance by cutting the functionality that reads/writes the options from/to the registry.

The `DialogPage` class provides the methods `LoadSettingsFromStorage` and `SaveSettingsToStorage` which are both virtual, so you can override them and call your custom persistence functionality instead.

```
public class OptionPageGrid : DialogPage
{
    private readonly ISettingsService<OptionPageGridSettings> settingsService = ...

    protected override IWin32Window Window
    {
        get
        {
            return new OptionPageGridWindow(this.settingsService);
        }
    }

    public override void LoadSettingsFromStorage()
    {
        this.settingsService.LoadSettingsFromStorage();
    }

    public override void SaveSettingsToStorage()
    {
        this.settingsService.SaveSettingsToStorage();
    }
}
```

The implementation of the `ISettingsService<T>` interface can be put into a shared assembly, to be referenced by the VSIX project and your stand-alone application (your test adapter assembly). The settings service could also use the Windows registry, or any other suitable storage...

```
public class WindowsRegistrySettingsService<T> : ISettingsService<T> 
{
    ...
}

public interface ISettingsService<T>
{
    T LoadSettingsFromStorage();
    void SaveSettingsToStorage();
}
```