# How do I access Visual Studio 2022 Extension tools options?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-sdk

I am creating an extension to Visual Studio 2022. I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-options-page?view=vs-2022 for adding options to the Tools Options property grid. In the experimental instance of Visual Studio, I can see the options and they persist (they are stored in a registry Hive in AppData if I understand correctly). According to that learning page, I can access the options in the OptionPageGrid instance (which is a DialogPage) by calling

```
OptionPageGrid page = (OptionPageGrid)GetDialogPage(typeof(OptionPageGrid));
```

However, when I do this, I always read the default values of the OptionPageGrid options, not the ones written and stored in the visual studio options grid. I can see the setters of the OptionPageGrid (DialogPage) options being hit in the debugger when the options page is opened in Visual Studio, but this appears to be a different instance of OpenPageGrid then the one retrieved by GetDialogPage. How do I access the options in the package?

#### Context

If you are interested, the code in question can be found at https://github.com/harmenwierenga/Fortran_VS2022/tree/0b73646d1c0a0096a149c199b1116b6ee1992f48.

#### Other Stackoverflow questions

I have seen [Visual Studio Extension: Access VS Options from arbitrary DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178255/visual-studio-extension-access-vs-options-from-arbitrary-dll), but this question is focused on accessing the options from other processes, which I do not think that I am doing. I have tried to use DTE objects, but I either got a null dte instance back (GetService) or I got a dte object (GetGlobalService) but then the program would hang when calling get_Properties on that object.

There is also [Visual Studio Debugger Extension get user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502945/visual-studio-debugger-extension-get-user-settings), but do I would prefer to use a stable API instead of hacking something that reads a path in the registry. Has that also changed? It appears that older versions of Visual Studio would write to the registry directly, but now the information is in AppData.

Comment: I have decided to parse the private registry for now, accessing it by GetReadOnlySettingsStore (combining the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779306/programmatically-finding-the-vs2017-most-recently-used-mru-solutions-and-proje and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502945/visual-studio-debugger-extension-get-user-settings). I will leave the question up, because I would like to know why GetDialogPage does not work the way I used it.